# Darktable: How to edit level on each RGB channel?

Tags: darktable, retouching

In order to fix blue haze on some pictures I usually use Gimp and correct the levels for each channel [as describe here for photoshop](http://www.lunacore.com/photoshop/tutorials/tut016.htm).

I know in darktable we can correct the levels but not for each channel and the tone plugin works in the LAB color space.

In darktable...

Is it possible to correct the levels for each channel ?

Is there another way to fix blue haze in pictures ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Color Balance module lets you adjust each of the RGB channels independently, though not with the same interface as Levels.

You can also target any of the modules towards parts of your image by setting the Blend to Parametric Mask. For example, you can apply Levels with the Parametric blending mode to areas that have a certain amount of blue in them, or that fall into a certain brightness range.

Depending on how strong the haze is -- and whether you actually want to remove the color or you want more sharpness -- Local Contrast or the Equalizer can be useful.

Comment: I've never tried the Color balance module. I'll give it a try and check out if I can do what I want.